# Understanding .babelrc

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have been searching for the answer related to presets key in the .babelrc. Can someone explain to me what does it mean to give 'env', 'stage-0', 'es2015' etc?
It would be great if I can get to know the better way to set the presets.

Comment: A preset tells babel which features should be used, here for example is the link for the es2015 preset with the full feature set: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/
Maybe this leads you in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

So I did some reading, here what I got to know.

In your webpack, when `babel-loader` is used as a transformer for `.jsx` files, it calls your .babelrc file. In your webpack you can pass options to the loader by using the options property. 
This loader also supports other loader-specific option:
1) cacheDirectory
2) cacheIdentifier
3) babelrc

Talking about babelrc, `babel-loader` pick up options from .babelrc files, if it is set as true (by default), else it will be ignored.

Babel acts as a transpiler for `jsx and es6 code`, for browser's understanding.
Using preset options you can tell babel how to do the understanding. This is done by providing presets in `.babelrc`.

Here are important presets to know:

1) ***es2015***: Compiles ES2015 to ES5. That will allow babel to transpile all the features of ES2015 if present in our file.
2) ***react***: Transform JSX into createElement calls.
3) ***env***: Contains all yearly presets so users won’t need to specify each one individually. It currently includes es2017, es2016, es2015.
4) ***latest***: It is deprecated now since it is same as env.

If you want to stay up to date, use the `env` preset for es6.

Ref: https://babeljs.io/docs/,
https://github.com/babel/babel-loader